# R, dplyr: build sets with one non-zero element per column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of values with thousands of rows and a couple dozen columns. For a given row, `R_0`, I'd like to iteratively find a complementary row, add it to a set, then find a row complementary to each element in the set. A complementary row is defined as:

1. if given row has a non-zero value for a column, then the complement must have a zero value for that column

The end result should be a set of SKUs whose combination should result in as few zero-valued columns as possible.

To illustrate, here is a toy dataframe (code at bottom):

```
  sku   p1_prop   p2_prop   p3_prop   p4_prop   p5_prop         rowTally
1   1   0         0         0         0.1634774 0                1
2   2   0.1617101 0.1700415 0         0         0                2
3   3   0         0         0         0         0.1385715        1
4   4   0         0         0.1785431 0         0.1399401        2
5   5   0.1682469 0         0         0         0                1
  totalDollarSales totalUnitSales dollarsPerRobot
1        386175.48       482131.9      0.80097474
2         13488.99       599605.9      0.02249643
3        382449.72       493592.0      0.77482973
4        869703.88       186299.0      4.66832335
5        340414.96       827390.6      0.41143200
```

I want a function that accepts the first SKU in the set as an input and finds all complementary elements to the set.

For example, I need a function `f`:

```
f(df=A, sku=1, rowTallyThreshold)
```

Process iteratively adds a SKU that is complementary to the existing set. If `rowTallyThreshold` = 3, then all rows where `rowTally<=3` can be added to the set:

```
[1] -> [1, 2] -> [1, 2, 3]
[1] -> [1, 2] -> [1, 2, 4]
```

If 'rowTallyThreshold` = 1, then all rows where rowTally<=1, or rows 1, 3 and 5, may potentially be added to the set:

```
[1] -> [1, 3] -> [1, 3, 5]
```

The resulting output should be all sets possible.

Code to generate MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
a = runif(n=25, min=0, max=0.18); a[a<0.13] = 0
A = as.data.frame(matrix(a, nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE))
A$rowTally <- rowSums(A != 0); 
A$sku <- seq(from = 1, to = 5)
A$totalDollarSales <- runif(n=5, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
A$totalUnitSales <- runif(n=5, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
names(A) <- c("p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "rowTally", "sku", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")
A <- A[c("sku", "p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "rowTally", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")]
A$dollarsPerRobot <- A$totalDollarSales/A$totalUnitSales
```

Comment: I don't understand what `rowTallyThreshold` means. Why can only rows <=3 be added when it is 3 or rows 1, 3, and 5 be added when it is 1? I presume there is a logic to it but I haven't guessed it yet.

Comment: For the purpose of this specific question, do you care about any columns besides `p1_prop   p2_prop   p3_prop   p4_prop   p5_prop   rowTally`?

Comment: @JonSpring `rowTallyThreshold` is what the `rowTally` column in the dataframe should be compared to. If `rowTally` <= `rowTallyThreshold`, then that row is a viable candidate to be added to the set, assuming that it has non-overlapping values for the columns

Comment: @JonSpring for this question, I only care about those columns

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)

## y matches to x iff y is zero when x is not zero
is_match <- function(x, y) {
  all((x != 0 & y == 0) | (x == 0))
}

## Find complement skus of sku
find_matches <- function(df, sku, rowTallyThreshold, vars) {
  ## Vector of main sku
  main_sku <- as.numeric(df[df$sku == sku, vars])
  ## Potential candidates
  potential <- df %>%
    filter(rowTally <= rowTallyThreshold)
  ## Indices of matches
  match_idx <- apply(potential[vars], 1, function(y){is_match(main_sku, y)})
  ## Skus of matches
  potential$sku[match_idx]
}

find_matches(A, 1, 3, c("p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me closer. The actual output should be: 
`[2,3]; [3]; [4]` because there are 3 possible combinations of skus/rows, including sku/row 1. The output should be a dataframe

Comment: I'm sorry your notation is not clear. Could you clarify what you want please? My function returns the skus as you asked in the question.